# How to incrementally add a list of values to a specific subset of columns in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop, valueerror

I'm able to add one row of values from a weather API (meteostat) to a specific subset of columns in a dataframe with the following code

```
Morel_df = pd.read_csv('C:/git/NOAA Weather/Morel_TreeSpecies_TEST_reformat_short.csv')
Test_Morel_df = Morel_df
x = morelParser('C:/git/NOAA Weather/Morel_TreeSpecies_TEST_reformat_short.csv')
location_vector = x.__next__()
point = (location_vector[0], location_vector[1], location_vector[2])
date = datetime.strptime(Test_Morel_df.loc[i, 'Date'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
temp_weather_df = callMeteostat(date, point)
temp_weather_list = temp_weather_df.values.tolist()
flattened_weather_list = [element for innerlist in temp_weather_list for element in innerlist]
i = 0

print(len(Test_Morel_df.loc[i, 'tavg_Before_30':'tsun_After_29']))
print(len(flattened_weather_list))

Test_Morel_df.loc[i, 'tavg_Before_30':'tsun_After_29'] = flattened_weather_list

Test_Morel_df.to_csv('C:/git/NOAA Weather/TEST_MOREL_WEATHER_SHORT.csv', index = False)
```

Since I want to iterate through every row of my main dataframe I created a simple for loop with the same process as above

```
Morel_df = pd.read_csv('C:/git/NOAA Weather/Morel_TreeSpecies_TEST_reformat_short.csv')
Test_Morel_df = Morel_df
x = morelParser('C:/git/NOAA Weather/Morel_TreeSpecies_TEST_reformat_short.csv')

for i in range(len(Test_Morel_df)):
            
    location_vector = x.__next__()
    point = (location_vector[0], location_vector[1], location_vector[2])
    date = datetime.strptime(Test_Morel_df.loc[i, 'Date'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    temp_weather_df = callMeteostat(date, point)
    
    temp_weather_list = temp_weather_df.values.tolist()

    flattened_weather_list = [element for innerlist in temp_weather_list for element in innerlist]

    print(len(Test_Morel_df.loc[i, 'tavg_Before_30':'tsun_After_29']))
    print(len(flattened_weather_list))
    
    Test_Morel_df.loc[i, 'tavg_Before_30':'tsun_After_29'] = flattened_weather_list

Test_Morel_df.to_csv('C:/git/NOAA Weather/TEST_MOREL_WEATHER_SHORT.csv', index = False)
```

Which results in the following error:

> ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value ')

This is confirmed with the print readouts, where the for loop flattened_weather_list loses 10 values compared to it's non-for loop counter part.

Here are the referenced functions that are called:

```
def callMeteostat(input_date, input_location):
    observation_dates = []
    observation_dates = list(dateRange(input_date))
    observation_location = convertLocation(input_location[0], input_location[1], 
    input_location[2])

    weather_data_call_before = Daily(observation_location, observation_dates[0], 
    observation_dates[1])


    weather_data_before = weather_data_call_before.fetch()

    return weather_data_before

def morelParser(morel_data_file_path):
    Morel_df = pd.read_csv(morel_data_file_path)


    for i in range(len(Morel_df)):
        input_location_list = (Morel_df.loc[i, 'DDLat'], Morel_df.loc[i, 'DDLon'], Morel_df.loc[i, 'Elevation_meters'], i)
        yield input_location_list

    return False

def dateRange(input_date):
    before_date = input_date - dt.timedelta(days = 30)
    after_date = input_date + dt.timedelta(days = 30)

    return before_date, after_date

def convertLocation(input_lat, input_lon, input_elev):
    input_location = Point(input_lat, input_lon, input_elev)

    return input_location
```

And here is the example csv file being referenced: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a2moQZUC7PQB9J_tClmPA4fEbRvGKdD7/view?usp=sharing

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Full traceback as requested

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\git\NOAA Weather\weather.py in <module>
    266 print(len(Test_Morel_df.loc[0, 'tavg_Before_30':'tsun_After_29']))
    267 print(len(flat_list))
--> 268 Test_Morel_df.loc[1, 'tavg_Before_30':'tsun_After_29'] = flat_list
    269 
    270 Test_Morel_df.to_csv('C:/git/NOAA Weather/TEST_MOREL_WEATHER_SHORT.csv', index = False)

~\miniconda3\envs\HistoricalWeatherData\lib\site packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    721 
    722 iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 723 iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
    724 
    725 def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~\miniconda3\envs\HistoricalWeatherData\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1728 if take_split_path:
   1729   # We have to operate column-wise
-> 1730   self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1731 else:
   1732   self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

~\miniconda3\envs\HistoricalWeatherData\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name)
   1806 
   1807 else:
-> 1808   raise ValueError(
   1809         "Must have equal len keys and value "
   1810         "when setting with an iterable"

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Comment: Post the error and the full trace

Comment: @Luke, got the traceback up. Tried my best with the formatting to make it look presentable.